# Delay occurring during horizontal slide in Chrome only

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, google-chrome

I'm creating this website where the pages slide horizontally. One of the pages (media) 
contains 10-15 pictures that are 60px in height and 80 px in width. The problem is when I make the pages "travel" from home to contact us, there's a slight delay in sliding caused by Media page in Chrome. However I noticed this slight delay isn't in Firefox or IE, in fact it goes smoothly. So I'm wondering if there's a fix other than re-sizing since I already made all of the pictures in smaller sizes (60kb or so).

Thank you for any suggestions in advance

The format is basically like this:

```
<div class="pannel"><br/> <br/>
    <a href="images/a (74).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (74).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (75).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (75).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (76).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (76).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (77).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (77).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (78).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (78).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (79).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (79).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (80).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (80).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (81).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (81).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (82).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (82).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (83).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (83).jpg"/></a>
    <a href="images/a (84).jpg" class="mediaPhotos"><img src="images/a (84).jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

---

```
.panel {    
    float               : left;
    height              : 800px;
    padding-right       : 1000px;
    width               : 850px;
}

.mediaPhotos img {
    border              : 3px solid #bfb886;
    border-radius       : 5px;
    height              : 60px;
    width               : 80px;
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#menuFloat a").bind("click",function(event){ event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");
   $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left, scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 1200);
 }); });
```

---

Basically `panel` is how big each page will be and float to the left of each page.

Link: http://permika-montreal.tk/new.php

Comment: Does this happens only the first time you scroll- before the images where in the viewport the first time (i.e. nor rendered yet)? Or does this happen all the time? How do you "slide"? Is it normal scrolling or some JavaScript controlled thing?

Comment: The slide effect is done by css and jquery. It happens even after page loads the first time. I'll post the link in a minute since idk how to explain "how it slides".

Comment: The effect looks the same for all pages in Chrome 24 on OS X. I can't speak for Chrome on Windows as it's different from the MAC version.

Comment: I'm using chrome 23 on Windows atm. Does the version matter?

Comment: I don't think that there is any difference between Chrome 23/24 in this case.

Comment: Mild tangent: avoid the spaces in your filenames. Modern browsers shouldn't have an issue with encoding the space properly, but you never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

through `chromes web-inspector` i removed the image `links` and it scrolled fine.  Noticed that you had the `link` images scaled down with `css`.  I think this large amount of data is causing your delay. Try re-sizing the images just for the links to limit the size of the panel.  this should get rid of the delay in scrolling with chrome.

Comment: But why does this delay only occur in Chrome and not firefox? I have re-size the pictures to 60kb or so...how much more smaller should i make it?

Comment: @user97751 I would size them to what you downsized them to with `cass`.  As for the why the delay only in chrome, not sure, might be how they deal with loading images when off frame.  Also when re-sizing the images use Photoshop` `save for web` if possible as it will allow you to see the size and download time with different settings.  Hope this helps your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what cass is. I used irfanviewer to resize the pictures.

Comment: @user97751 sorry ment "scaled down with `css`"  Also check out [Progressive jpegs: a new best practice](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/) she talks about larger images and how they load i.e. content and image pops versus saving progressive `jpgs` to have lower resolution images that transition to higher resolution ones so content isn't broken on your site.  Not sure if it would help on your site as the images are loaded when the user is on the home page area of your site, good reading though and thought i would share.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the width and height for the images!

Comment: This is rather terse, explain more what is wrong and how this resolves the issue.